# Error "illegal start of expression"

Tags: java

estoy creando una clase para comprobar que el numero introducido es correcto. Conozco el uso de las excepciones, pero de momento no puedo utilizarlas. Me salen dos errores, uno de while y otro de **illegal start os expression** y no se porque sale esto.

[image: error]

```
   public class miScanner {

   private final Scanner scanner;

public miScanner() {
    this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}


public boolean leeEntero() {

    boolean esDatoValido = false;
    int numeroEnteroValido = -1;

    do {

        if (esDatoValido) {
              numeroEnteroValido = this.scanner.nextInt();
            esDatoValido = true;

        }else{
            System.out.println("El dato introducido no es un número entero");



    } while(!esDatoValido);

    return esDatoValido;
}



public double leeDecimal() {

    boolean esDatoValido = false;
    double numeroDecimalValido = Double.NaN;

    do {

        if (esDatoValido) {
            numeroDecimalValido = this.scanner.nextDouble();
            esDatoValido = true;

        }else{
            System.out.println("El dato introducido no es un número decimal");
        }

    } while(!esDatoValido);

    return numeroDecimalValido;
}

public boolean leeBooleano() {

    boolean esDatoValido = false;
    boolean booleanoValido = Boolean.FALSE;

    do {

        if (booleanoValido) {
             booleanoValido = this.scanner.nextBoolean();
            esDatoValido = true;


        }else{
            System.out.println("El dato introducido no es un booleano");
        }

    } while(!esDatoValido);

    return booleanoValido;
}

public String leeString() {

    return this.scanner.nextLine();
}
}
```

Comment: Faltó cerrar una llave `}` dentro del `do-while`.

Comment: Según tienes las condiciones montadas siempre te va salir que el dato no es valido y se imprimirá eso hasta el infinito sin pedirte leer ningún dato nuevo ¿no? Sólo te puede funcionar `leerString()`... Aunque no tenga que ver con tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por convencion todas las Clases Java deben comenzar con mayuscula , tu clase debe quedar asi , ya que te falta cerrar una llave ( } ) en la instruccion else

```
    public class miScanner {

private final Scanner scanner;

public miScanner() {
    this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public boolean leeEntero() {

    boolean esDatoValido = false;
    int numeroEnteroValido = -1;

    do {

        if (esDatoValido) {
              numeroEnteroValido = this.scanner.nextInt();
            esDatoValido = true;

        }else{
            System.out.println("El dato introducido no es un número entero");
        }


    } while(!esDatoValido);

    return esDatoValido;
}

public double leeDecimal() {

    boolean esDatoValido = false;
    double numeroDecimalValido = Double.NaN;

    do {

        if (esDatoValido) {
            numeroDecimalValido = this.scanner.nextDouble();
            esDatoValido = true;

        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("El dato introducido no es un número decimal");
        }

    } while (!esDatoValido);

    return numeroDecimalValido;
}

public boolean leeBooleano() {

    boolean esDatoValido = false;
    boolean booleanoValido = Boolean.FALSE;

    do {

        if (booleanoValido) {
            booleanoValido = this.scanner.nextBoolean();
            esDatoValido = true;

        } else {
            System.out.println("El dato introducido no es un booleano");
        }

    } while (!esDatoValido);

    return booleanoValido;
}

public String leeString() {

    return this.scanner.nextLine();
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta cerrar una llave en el else...

```
      do {

            if (esDatoValido) {
                  numeroEnteroValido = this.scanner.nextInt();
                  esDatoValido = true;

            }else{
                 System.out.println("El dato introducido no es un número entero");
            }


      } while(!esDatoValido);
```